# Can a Barrel block Gatling?

Tags: bang

Can a barrel (or the character whose power emulates a barrel) be used to attempt to mitigate the Bang! effect from a Gatling card?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "Any card with a Missed! symbol can be
>   used to cancel the effect of a card
>   with a BANG! symbol",

says the  "Remember" section of the latest version of the rules.

Gatling has a BANG! symbol, barrel has a Missed! symbol.  They're a match made in heaven, or at least Boot Hill.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Barrel can be used to block a Gatling, as well as other cards with *Bang!* symbols, such as Knife, Buffalo Rifle, Punch (funny, right?), Derringer, Howitzer and so forth. Of course, it won't work against Duel or Indians!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. The Gatling just applies a Bang! to all other players. So, from each other player's perspective, it shouldn't be treated any differently than if a Bang! card had been played against them directly, in which case the Barrel (or character ability) would be perfectly fine.