# Gatling and backfire in Bang!

Tags: bang

If a gatling is played by player A and player B uses a backfire (as it counts as a Missed!), is player A the target of a Bang! ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/can-a-barrel-block-gatling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From the rulebook:

> Even though the **Gatling shoots a BANG! to all the other players**, it is not considered a BANG! card.

(Emphasis mine).

And the [Wikipedia for Bang!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!_(card_game)#The_Valley_of_Shadows) says:

> BackFire – Counts as Missed!. Any player who targeted you with Bang! is now a target of Bang!.

When you play Gatling, you target every other player with a Bang!. So BackFire will respond to Gatling just like it would to a regular Bang! card.

Comment: but the rulebook says `[Gatling] it is not considered a BANG!`

Comment: @Hakim No, it say it is not considered a Bang! Card. It IS considered a Bang!. A Bang! Card is one way to shoot a a Bang!. The difference being that you can only play one Bang! Card per turn, but you can use any number of other things that cause a Bang!.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the clarification. I did not see the word `card` at the end of your sentence, it makes sense now

Comment: No problem! Bang! uses icons heavily for card effects. What matters for Gatling is that it has the Bang! icon on it.